# iOS 6 Facebook posting procedure ends up with "remote_app_id does not match stored id"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

This is my third question about posting on Facebook.

Although this may be a duplicate of [Mac OS X Facebook login failed - no stored remote_app_id for app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555799/mac-os-x-facebook-login-failed-no-stored-remote-app-id-for-app) but I decided to post separate question because we have iOS here but not MAC OS.

A few days ago I posted a question [iOS 6 Facebook posting procedure ends up with "remote_app_id does not match stored id" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-permissions-alert-view) The problem is still the same I can't perform a post but now I've got an error:

`error is: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: remote_app_id does not match stored id." UserInfo=0xa260270 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: remote_app_id does not match stored id.}`

The code you may find in my previous question.
Does anyone know what's going on?
What is remote and stored app ids?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 6 Facebook posting procedure ends up with "remote_app_id does not match stored id" error](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor)

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate if you read question carefully you will find that initially there was two different problems

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This happens when authenticating using iOS6 Accounts API.

All you have to do to get it working is:

- log in to the developers.facebook.com
- set your app to be an iOS Native app
- type in your app's bundle ID.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you!! I don't know why it took me so long to find your post... You'd think this would be easier to find in the setup (I'm using parse, which didn't mention this in their latest update)

Comment: Don't forget add rows "FacebookAppId", "FacebookDisplayName", "URL types" to plist https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/851559_148282688685691_1981352615_n.png

Comment: Oops, the bundle id in facebook settings is case sensitive.

Comment: My issue was similar: I changed my app's bundle ID in xcode and forgot to update on developers.facebook.com. This might help if your FB login was once working and now isn't.

Comment: Thank you, this works and you can even specify several bundles (case sensitive!) there. Here is my public domain app to demo this: https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyFacebook

Answer (score 16):

just copy and paste the bundle ID you have in your xcode, into where facebook wants the Bundle ID

a sample pic is here http://kosovich.org.ua/tmp/facebook_ios6_app_howto.png

Say for eg, your bundle ID is named com.parse. (e.g. com.parse.myDateApp) but that into bundle ID. And make sure you check the box that says Facebook login

Answer (score 7):

We had the same problem, but since Facebook is changing layouts a lot, I'm posting what solved our problem with pictures again. The solution is similar to Andrew Kosovich's answer, but with new interface there are some changes.

1. **Login** to your [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com) and select your problematic app.
2. Go to app's settings

   [image: Settings screenshot]
3. **Check** if **iOS** is already added. If you find iOS section, **go to step 4**, otherwise add it, by clicking **Add platform** button.

   [image: Add platform screenshot]
4. Enter correct **bundle ID** of your application into the appropriate box.

   [image: iOS platform screenshot]

After entering correct details the login with Facebook SDK should work.

***Warning: Do not forget to enable Facebook access to your application in the Settings application of the specific iOS device.***

Answer (score 0):

When ever you sign up to developers.facebook.com you get a unique id http://developers.facebook.com/

Register your app over there and u get a unique app id and secret id you have to use that when you use your facebook sdk for integrating your app

the fbappname and fbappid then are to be entered in plist which will let you create your session

Answer (score 0):

All developers of a particular app, should be known to Facebook. While the application is in Sandbox mode (i.e. developer only access), all every user who want to use the Facebook platform, for testing/developing the application, will have to be added as a developer.

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com
2. Your app
3. Roles
4. Add Facebook ID of the developer / administrator

To know your Facebook ID: [findmyfacebookid.com](http://findmyfacebookid.com)