# iOS 6 facebook sdk 3.1.1 login error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I tried to login using facebook followed the facebook tutorial in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/ to implement it but after the alert view asking me to allow my app use your data and press ok the error

**The operation could not be completed . (com.facebook.sdk error 2)**

note that iam in the simulatore and i entered FB my account inside setting and it is logged correctly.

debugging the issue it and the result of the error is as following :

> (NSError *) $1 = 0x0ac77290 Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0xac77450 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: no stored remote_app_id for app" UserInfo=0xaa91d40 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: no stored remote_app_id for app}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide your app bundle id in app settings on developers.facebook.com

[iOS 6 Facebook posting procedure ends up with "remote_app_id does not match stored id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671420/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor)

Comment: I had a similar issue. the error comes up when the i switched the fb user from setting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device This solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after signing out of facebook from Device Setting's.

Comment: This is more of a workaround! If you are signing out of your FB from settings, then it follows a different flow (opens a browser). When user uses the app, he is not gonna sign out of his settings to make it work for your app.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error could be come due to this reason:-

1. Might be your bundle id is different over
   developers.facebook.com/aaps
2. your are might be not giving right permission to your app.
3. You are not enabling facebook app in your iphone facebook settings.

Please follow given below link

[Facebook Registration : The operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052078/facebook-registration-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-com-facebook-sdk-er/16052146?noredirect=1#comment22908493_16052146)

I hope this would clear your all doubt.

Answer (score 0):

In ios 6 with fb sdk 3.1.1. Please pass permissions param as "nil or email" in "[FBSessio openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions..." method. Here my code it was works great.

```
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )

-(void)showFBLogin
{
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email, publish_actions, publish_stream", nil];

#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
    permissions = nil; or NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",nil];
#endif

    NSLog(@"\npermissions = %@", permissions);
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"\nfb sdk error = %@", error);
         switch (state) {
             case FBSessionStateOpen:
                 [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
                  ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error) {
                          //success
                      } 
                  }];
                 break;
             case FBSessionStateClosed:
                 //need to handle
                 break;
             case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                 //need to handle
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to the settings app of your iPhone.
Open your Facebook Settings
Scroll down to your app and make sure your app allows facebook interaction.