# Facebook Registration : The operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 2)

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, xcode4.6

I am developing an ios phonegap application. For registration i use [phonegap facebook plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin). It worked fine for the first time. But now when i try to register it isn't working. I haven't changed anything. I use Xcode version 4.6.1 and cordova version 2.4.0.

[image]

Figure shows my Facebook developers page.

What am i doing wrong?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I think this will fix your issue:

1. Go to you Facebook app in your Facebook account.
2. Click edit your app.
3. Go to Basic info tab.
4. Sandbox Mode: check this as Disable
5. Save the setting.

This will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but, you know why the sandbox does not worked properly?

Comment: I think because Facebook login functionality works on SSO (Single Sign On). our app get redirect to Facebook app (if exist) in the device and take all information from there without making login separate for each app. I think this should be the reason.

Answer (score 6):

First of all make sure about your Bundle Id should be correct.

And change your setting like it

[image]

Change sandbox setting disabled.

Also change your P-list setting like it

[image]

It will work fine. If you will face this problem again please let me know.

Comment: Still same error. I did every thing as you mentioned. What do i do now?

Comment: Check your bundle identifier in your project P-list. It should be same as you mentioned in developers.facebook.com.

Comment: Also add this two thing in your project plist

 1.> URL Type
       item 0(Editor)     
           Document Role    :   Editor
           URL identifier   :   Your bundle Id
           URL Schemes      
                    Item 0 : fb"plus your app secret key "
                    Item 1 : Your bundle Id


 2.> FacebookAppID      :  "your app secret key"

Comment: Initially, i populated the fields you mentioned with "AppId" , Now changed to "App Secret Key". Now when i click "Register with facebook" button "Error occured. Please try again later" message is showing.

Comment: First of all delete app and reinstall it in your device .

Then follow P-List change from above given image.

and check your code with this given link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838118/facebook-authorization-fails-on-ios6-when-switching-fb-account-on-device

Comment: I get warning "Access token is depreciated". Is it a problem?

Comment: Sorry change app secret key with app id. It work fine for you

Comment: Hello , i can follow this all step but when i can send message to friends wall , then i get error , please give me solution of this problem....
Error: HTTP status code: 403
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Comment: This is due to lack of permissions. Allow publish_actions permissions to post messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you get warning "Access token is depreciated".  Please add or replace your code line by this two lines where you are passing permissions to your app

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; 

NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];
```

If u are doing all the thing right then please check "status" value. If it is 257 then please enable your app in your IPhone facebook settings.

Here is the code that can help you to understand in better way

```
   [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                                                     FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
     {
      if (error)
      {
              NSLog(@"error===%@   status====%u",error,status);
              // Handle errors
                 [self handleAuthError:error];
         }
         else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
         {
             [self getData];
         }
     }];


-(void)handleAuthError:(NSError *)error{
    NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;

    if (error.fberrorShouldNotifyUser) {
        // If the SDK has a message for the user, surface it.
        alertTitle = @"Something Went Wrong";
        alertMessage = error.fberrorUserMessage;
    } else if (error.fberrorCategory == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
        // The user has cancelled a login. You can inspect the error
        // for more context. For this sample, we will simply ignore it.
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login");
    } else {
        // For simplicity, this sample treats other errors blindly.
        alertTitle  = @"Unknown Error";
        alertMessage = @"Error. Please try again later.";
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
    }

    if (alertMessage) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
```

I hope it would work.

Comment: I am getting status == 257 isn't there any other way to make app works without enable it in Settings in Facebook? I'm using Facebook SDK only because I wan't to let use my app for users that have disabled Facebook in Settings

Comment: Hi @Michal, i have resolved your problem. I have updated my code . Please check it and let me know if any problem occurs. Thanks

Comment: Facebook SDK is messy as **** This 2 lines of code didn't help. But funny thing - app didn't work on iPod but did work on iPhone 5 with identical settings, after I reinstalled Facebook app on iPod it started working fine. I think it's very very hard do predict all possible situations that can occur with Facebook SDK. In other hand iOS Social Framework works great but often people disable Facebook in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a case when you have 2 or more items in the URL types array in your info.plist. The Facebook related item should be the first, otherwise you get the error 2. This is probably a Facebook SDK bug.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to the settings app of your iPhone.
Open your Facebook Settings
Scroll down to your app and make sure your app allows facebook interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Download Facebook new version and it should work. I had same error with sdk version 3.13.1.Then, I replaced it with sdk version 3.14.1. Then, it worked for me.