# How to use SLRequest for change via iOS to via <AppName>

Tags: ios, facebook, slrequest

I goes through many link and tutorials but not working for me.
Can anybody explain me How to use SLRequest for change via iOS to via MyAppName ?? step by step or give me some links which gives this solution in step by step.

EDIT: I have tried.  Below is my code may be help.

```
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore
                                          accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

        // Specify App ID and permissions
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"012345678912345",
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                              };

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                          options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
                                              if (granted) {
                                                  NSArray *accounts = [accountStore
                                                                       accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
                                                  facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                              }
                                              else
                                                  {
                                                      // Handle Failure
                                                  }
                                          }];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": @"My first iOS 6 Facebook posting "};

    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest 
                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST 
                              URL:feedURL 
                              parameters:parameters];

    feedRequest.account = self->facebookAccount;

    [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, 
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         // Handle response
     }];
}
```

Comment: "change via iOS to via MyAppName" makes no sense. Post the code you have and say what it does wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set you facebook setting using [Facebook developer account setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052078/facebook-registration-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-com-facebook-sdk-er/16052146#16052146)

then reset your simular or delete app from device.

Add and import this frameworks

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

use this code for further process

in yourclass.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)ACAccountStore *accountStore;
```

in yourclass.m file

```
@synthesize accountStore;

- (IBAction)facebookButtonTouch:(id)sender {

    if (self.accountStore == nil) 
        self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];


    __block ACAccount *facebookAccount = nil;

      ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

      NSArray * permissions = @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions",@"email"];
      NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"your app id", ACFacebookAppIdKey, permissions, ACFacebookPermissionsKey, ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe, ACFacebookAudienceKey, nil];



   [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                          options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *readPermissions = @[@"read_stream", @"read_friendlists"];
             [options setObject:readPermissions forKey: ACFacebookPermissionsKey];

             [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                 if(granted && error == nil) {
                     /**
                      * We now should have some read permission
                      * Now we may ask for write permissions or
                      * do something else.
                      **/
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"error is: %@",[error description]);
                 }
             }];

             NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
             facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
         }
         else {

             NSLog(@"error.localizedDescription======= %@", error.localizedDescription);
         }

     }];

    NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
    facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];



//-------------- start code for posting message on wall via SLRequest------------------
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": @"Hi Friends i m ....."};

    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                              URL:feedURL
                              parameters:parameters];

    feedRequest.account = facebookAccount;

    [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"responseData %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
     }];

//-------------- end code for posting message on wall via SLRequest------------------

}
```

i hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: This Code will post massage on wall of FB or we have to do anything else?? Help me i don't know anything about new FB integration.
I did above but nothing happening.

Comment: Hi python, thanks for reply. Let me clear with your requirements that you want in your application. Then i will update my code according to your requirement. You want to post message or just want to take feed???

Comment: Hi python, i have updated my code with post message via SLRequest. Please have a look and please let me know your feed back. Thanks

Comment: chandan Yes i want post message on FB wall. I tried new code even, it is not posting message. i comment this #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> then also app running fine. Not getting result.

Comment: My updated code working here fine. You can not send same message again and again so you have to change it with every post. Please check your developer act setting and ACFacebookAppIdKey inside my answer's first link "Facebook developer account setting". It defiantly helps you. Please let me know if you still facing this problem

Comment: AS response I am getting this {"error"{"message":"An Active access token must be used to query information about the current user","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
Can you suggest where i am getting wrong.

Comment: Please this is due to facebook login. Please login in your facebook app from your setting then you can able to post. You are not logged in facebook app. Please login first then run your app again and then send message. It would work fine. Please let me know your feedback . Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30564/discussion-between-chandan-and-python)

Comment: It is working, but big problem is when i changes Facebook account setting with other account it wont work for me ??

Comment: Hi python plz check your ACFacebookAppIdKey and confirm it via developer account . Might be you will have to update plist value for it

Comment: Hi python plz let me know that is it working or not. So i can help u

Comment: Hi friend.. u help me lot. thanks first for that. It is working but when changed one fb account to other from setting, its giving OAuthException.
Do u know any solution for this. Eager to accept ans.

Comment: Hi python, Sorry for late reply . Please disable deep linking from settings and use my updated code with different different app id and enjoy it. But always remind that before implementation of it delete existing app from device

Comment: Hi python, have you check it ? I am waiting for your response. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @python, I don't have.

Comment: Use this link for twitter
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-slrequest