# Facebook Sdk for ios publish -dark screen

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to share on Facebook.
But every time it request permission to publish, it will direct a screen
"You have authorized to the "AppName"". When I click on OK. It brought me to blank screen.

Here is my flow.
1. Login to Facebook
2. Request for publish permission. 
3. Publish to Facebook wall.

```
 [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            // Now have the permission
                                            [self publishStory];
                                        } else {
                                            // Facebook SDK * error handling *
                                            // if the operation is not user cancelled
                                            if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                                                [self presentAlertForError:error];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }];
```

Comment: Did u set up ur facebookAppId and URL schemes.... ?

Comment: Yes. I can login to facebook.

Comment: [see this ][1] , may helps you, post some more code


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052078/facebook-registration-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-com-facebook-sdk-er

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

while opening the session specify permission to publish post

```
   NSArray  *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",nil]; //permissions
  return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state,NSError *error)
```

and whenever you want to publish, do like this

```
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:TextView.text, @"message",nil]; // set the formats
if([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] != NSNotFound)
{
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         NSString *alertText;
         if(error)
         {
              //if error occurred

         }
         else
         {
             //successfull
         }

     }];

    }

 }
```