# Post Twitter and Facebook without composer view

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

I have a view where the user can input any comment and he can share this comment on Facebook and Twitter. So far all is working fine, but after pushing the corresponding Facebook or Twitter button, to share, a Composer View is opened and the user has again to push Share.

I want to avoid this and not showing the Composer view. Is this possible and if yes, how. Is there an issue with Apple when posting directly on Facebook and Twitter, I know that Apple rejects apps when they are sending emails without the email composer view.

Comment: for twitter u can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459252/how-to-post-on-twitter-by-hiding-slcomposeviewcontroller-tweetsheettweet-instan/18460093#18460093

Comment: for Facebook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048087/facebook-sdk-for-ios-publish-dark-screen/18050985#18050985