# FacebookSDK for IOS 6 using FBLoginView

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad, loginview, authorize

I have an iPhone IOS 4.3 and iPad IOS 6 apps both using the same code to login a user. FBLoginView work on iPhone with IOS4.3. On my IPad app that use IOS 6 only show the dialog saying the Application would like to access your photos, and post to your friends on your behalf with 2 buttons 'Don't Allow' and 'OK'. I pressed ok but the Facebook stay not logged in.

What other setup do I need ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using new SDK from here. http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: Yes ... I used FBLoginView inside SDK...

Comment: Please check the answer of the below two questions, that will help for you. 1. [iOS 6 Facebook posting procedure ends up with “remote_app_id does not match stored id”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671420/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor) 2. [iOS 6 Facebook posting procedure ends up with “remote_app_id does not match stored id” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor)

Comment: Thanks i will look at it later after I finished other thing.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was because I was using offline_access.

I had following code:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
             [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access", @"email", nil]];
```

The error went away after changing to:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
             [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil]];
```

More details on offline_access here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, login can be done using the following code. Put NSLog inside to get error.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", nil] allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  // session might now be open.
                                  NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);
                              }]
```

Comment: Can we use FBLoginView instead of this

Comment: I've got Don't Allow or OK option in the dialog. When I clicked on OK, the application still not log in.

Comment: Did you check if the delegate method "- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView" is getting called?

Comment: Not the iPad that using IOS 6 in the emulator but it work on iPhone that use IOS 4.3 simulator

Comment: Reset your simulator and run "FacebookSDK/Samples/HelloFacebookSample". See if it is working fine.

Comment: Yes the sample work but i follow the same setting for the FBLoginView and still not working

Comment: Ok, use the below method to trace out the error.                                     [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", nil] allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  // session might now be open.
                                  NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);
                              }]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, instead of FBLoginView, for now, use the below method to trace out the error. Then, you can switch back to FBLoginView.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", nil] allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  // session might now be open.
                                  NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);
                              }]
```

Comment: Error - Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0xb371320 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: no stored remote_app_id for app" UserInfo=0xa76aab0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: no stored remote_app_id for app}}